# Getting Descriptive Text out of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"Store":["a","b","c","c","d"],"Goods":["x","x","x","y","x"]})

  Store Goods
0     a     x
1     b     x
2     c     x
3     c     y
4     d     x
```

I want a descriptive output that tells me each good is available in which stores, like this

```
The Good x is available at:
a
b
c
d

The Good y is available at:
c
```

so I tried this

```
for index, row in df.groupby(['Goods', 'Store']).count().iterrows():
    print("The Good " + index[0] + " is available at:" + "\n" + index[1] + "\n" + "\n")
```

and got this

```
The Good x is available at:
a
The Good x is available at:
b
The Good x is available at:
c
The Good x is available at:
d
The Good y is available at:
c
```

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try `groupby`

```
for x , y in df.groupby('Goods'):
    print('The Good {} is avaliable at:'.format(x))
    print (y['Store'].to_string(index=False))
    
The Good x is avaliable at:
a
b
c
d
The Good y is avaliable at:
c
```